# What is the right way to implement setUpTestData style behaviour in py.test

Tags: pytest, pytest-django

I have a bunch of fixture stuff that I want to do once for the test class but I also don't want the associated tests messing with it.

I don't really get the py.test fixture system yet so I'm not seeing how this is supposed to be done.

In vanilla Django this stuff is achieved with setUpTestData which lets you create some fixtures in the DB once for the test class. Then at the start of each test case it drops a transaction savepoint and at the end of each test it resets to that save point. (This is in addition to it transactioning around the entire class so as to leave a clean db at the end.)

I could get this functionality by inheriting off Django's TransactionTestCase but pytest-django seems to want to run without that and I've achieved everything else I need without doing so.

Answer (score 3):

I've looked around for this quite a lot, and the best I could find is this pytest plugin, which I have not tested myself:

https://github.com/tipsi/pytest-tipsi-django

Per the pytest-django issue list, it looks like this has been raised before, but there is no movement towards a fix:

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/issues/514